# Req.body is empty while using Post Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, testing, backend

App.js

```
app.use(express.json({limit:"30mb",extended:true}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
```

route.js

```
router.route("/register").post(registerUser)`
```

importing Routes in app.js

```
import userRoute from './routes/user.route.js';

app.use("/users",userRoute);

const {fullName,email,username,password} = req.body;
console.log("req.body: ",req.body);
```

output:

```
req.body:  {}
Error: All input is required
```

I'm trying to register user with files but req.body is empty if I'm trying to use normal form in postman but if I'm trying x-www-form-urlencoded it works but cann't upload file there

Comment: Within postman, you need to use either `x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` (Or something of a similar name). I am unsure of what exactly you mean by normal form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In route.js File

```js
router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
    const {fullName, email, username, password} = req.body; 
    console.log("req.body: ",req.body);
});
```

Using this code.
I think it resolve your problem.

If nothing happened, please check sending message in Network of the Browser.

forgot to use multer middleware in route now it is working

```js
router.route("/register").post(upload.single("profilePic"),registerUser);
```

Comment: It looks like they are using the same code, not sure if that would help.